# Make the field Bold based on other filed value in SSRS report 2008

Tags: reporting-services

To meet my expectation, I have tried this code in fontweight expression as well as field value expression

```
=iif(fields!RATE_SELECTED="A","BOLD","NORMAL")
```

I end up with an exception

Error BC30518: Overload resolution failed because no accessible '=' can be called with these arguments

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `.Value` in expression.
 It should be:

`=iif(Fields!RATE_SELECTED.Value="A","Bold","Normal")`

Also, it should be `"Bold","Normal"` instead of "BOLD","NORMAL"
and *due to some SSRS bug*, if you try this, and it still doesn't work,then the *trick* is:

Try first clearing the previous values and then Click `OK >> OK` till you again reach the *Report Designer screen*.
From here, again *right click* your report item, say *TextBox*, `right click >>TextBox properties >>Font>> fx` (*near Bold*) and when you here

 [image]

then, instead of manually writing the full expression, write only `=iif(` then click on *`Fields`* [see fig] and choose `RATE_SELECTED` ,similarly click on *`Constants`* and double click **Bold,** and then **Normal** 
then, with your manual edit, the final expression should be like 
`=iif(Fields!RATE_SELECTED.Value="A","Bold","Normal")`

HTH